# Find element from 3 arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to find element from 3 arrays and create string using values. I have tried and given the output. But I want to know that, is there any better solution for this.

```
var numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
var letters = ['A','B','C','D','E'];
var romans = ['I','II','III','IV','V'];

function findInArray(input){
    var index = -1;
    if(numbers.indexOf(input) >= 0){
        index = numbers.indexOf(input);        
    } else if(letters.indexOf(input) >= 0){
        index = letters.indexOf(input);
    } else if(romans.indexOf(input) >= 0){
        index = romans.indexOf(input);
    }

    if(index > -1){
        var data = '{"numbers":"'+numbers[index]+'","letters":"'+letters[index]+'","romans":"'+romans[index]+'"}';
        console.log(data);
    }
}

findInArray('2');
```

output : `{"numbers":"2","letters":"B","romans":"II"}`

Comment: You are searching each array twice.

Comment: Hint: 1.  Don't invoke `indexOf` twice for each array.  2.  What if tomorrow there is one more array to be searched?  Would you add another else if?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to check if **indexOf** exists for each of the arrays. You can just find the **max** value of **index** for all the three arrays.

If the **argument** exists in any of the array, it will return a positive values (which results in *true*)

Then you can simply return the concatenation of the result using the **template strings**

```js
var numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
var letters = ['A','B','C','D','E'];
var romans = ['I','II','III','IV','V'];

var findInArray = (i) => {
  var index = Math.max(numbers.indexOf(i), letters.indexOf(i), romans.indexOf(i));
  if (index) {
    return `{numbers: ${numbers[index]}, letters: ${letters[index]}, romans: ${romans[index]}}`;
  } 
}

console.log(findInArray('2'));
console.log(findInArray('D'));
console.log(findInArray('V'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Vishal,

@Jonas has used a self executing function.

For example it will output `25`

```
(function(x){
  return x*x;
}(5));
```

here `5`is the parameter of this self executing function which will output to `25`

Back to answer; When you convert his answer to raw it will look something like

```
const findInArray = val => (i => ({ //i = 1 here
   numbers: numbers[1],
   letters: letters[1],
   romans: romans[1]
 }))(Math.max(1,-1,-1) //will output 1);
```

Hope it makes sense.

resource - http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/

Answer (score 0):

Might be simpler with:

```
const findInArray = val => (i => ({
   numbers: numbers[i],
   letters: letters[i],
   romans: romans[i]
 }))(Math.max(
   numbers.indexOf(val), 
   letters.indexOf(val),
   romans.indexOf(val)
));
```

Comment: Adding an explanation will help others too !

Comment: @Jonas  please provide explanation

Comment: Imo.. a self executable function does not make this problem simpler. It's hard to read and not necessary at all. KISS (Keep It Stupid Simple)

Comment: @Dieterg, It is most convenient answer IMO. Would you please judge your statement ?

Comment: Write out the self executable function like @Anurag Singh Bisht

Comment: @Dieterg, That is not a self executable function at all.

Comment: I know, I actually meant to write it out as a seperate function. Anyway it does the same but for most programmers a seperate function is alot easier to read, The fact that 2 people asked for explanation says enough imo :)